# Open a textfile in PhoneGap on android

Tags: android, file, cordova

I try to open a textfile in my android app (build with phonegap 3.5) and i also added the File Api Plugin.

But i always get null at the second alert as output of the reader.

HTML-Input:

```
<input type="file" id="file" onchange="handle_files(this.files)">
```

JS-Function:

```
function handle_files(files) {
    for (i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        file = files[i];
        alert(file.name);
        var reader = new FileReader();  
        reader.onloadend = function(e) {
            alert(e.target.result);
        };
        reader.readAsText(file);
        reader.onerror = function(stuff) {
            console.log("error", stuff);
            console.log (stuff.getMessage());
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to execute with a console that should show you extra info, probably a configuration error (not a coding problem):

I give you 3 alternatives:

- Execute App with Ripple: http://ripple.incubator.apache.org/
- If you have Kit-kat device try with your CordovaWebview

  ￼if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
      CordovaWebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
  }
- Using Winre